# Customized Drop Down List

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-selectors

so I'm designing a customized DropDownList I need to make it as a normal Drop Down List to the user
here is the HTML

```html
<div class="select" id="long">
  <img src="img/pin.jpg" class="select_img" />
  <div class="select_text">
    Newsletter
  </div>
  <div class="select_arrow">
    <>
  </div>
  <ul>
    <li>this</li>
    <li>that</li>
    <li>duck</li>
    <li>deck</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="select" id="short">
  <img src="img/clk.jpg" class="select_img" />
  <div class="select_text">
    Contact
    </div>
    <div class="select_arrow">
      <>
    </div>
    <ul>
      <li>this</li>
      <li>that</li>
      <li>duck</li>
      <li>deck</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

So as you see I have here two DropDownList items one is long and the other is short 
and here is the CSS

```
/*ID's*/

img#logo {display: inline-block;float: left; height: 55px; width: 155px;}
div#long {margin-left: 330px;}
div#long .select_text { width: 85px;}
div#long ul {width: 147px; display: none;}
div#short {margin-left: 16px;}
div#short .select_text { width: 57px;}
div#short ul {width: 119px; display: none;}

/* Classes */

.select{
    position: relative;
    height: 31px;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 10px;
    font-family: nexa;
    color: #959595;
    font-size: 10px;

}
.select_img{
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    width: 31px;
    height: 31px;
    background-color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.select_text{
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    height: 31px;
    background-color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-indent: 3px;
    line-height: 32px;
}
.select_arrow{
    display: inline-block;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    background-color: #ebebeb;
    color: #959595;
    width: 31px;
    height: 30px;
    border-bottom: 1px #d8d8d8 solid;
    font-size: 11px;
    line-height: 32px;
    text-indent: 6px;
    font-family: Quicksand;
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-indent: 10px;
}

.select ul li{
    text-indent: 34px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;

}
.select ul li:hover{
    background-color: #f26c4f;
}
```

Now, my Question is:

When I click on any of the `div.select` children I want to show the `ul` of the same div I clicked, I tried `$(this).children('ul).slideDown('normal');` but that didn't work :(

I need a way like this, I want to use `$(this)` selector

**I don't want** to use a way like this:

```
$('#select_img, #select_text, select_arrow').click(function(){
    $('#long ul').slideDown('normal');
});
```

I want it generic: when I click on any of the `div` elements its `ul` shows.

Comment: Hmm indeed, do you have an error message in your console?

Comment: please explain more if you don't want to target the children elements. WHat do you want. Show the code you tried that didn't work

Comment: I want to run the code what ever was the element of the div.... let's assume in the future I changed the elements inside the div I need the code runs any way I DO want to target the children elements but by the parent div not by neither the class name nor the id

Comment: and that explanation makes no sense

Comment: So, you want this `<ul>` element to look like a `<select>` element? And to have it show, by clicking its parent/ancestor `<div>`?

Comment: exactly @DavidThomas and taking into consideration that the user can't click the parent div because it's in the background he'll click one of its children I want exactly this I want to select it's children whatever they were

Comment: @SamerAllahham clicks bubble, so if you click a child it registers on  parent also unless using methods to stop the propagation. WHere is the code you tried that didn't work! It should work

Comment: Thanks for all of you for helping me and thank for every one who gave me -1 I don't know why I'm here to ask a question and it's my right I don't know why somebody would give me -1 I didn't do anything wrong I just wanted to understand something and my question does not deserve this any way thank you for disappointing me cuz this site is for tutoring people not for review any one I will delete my question and leave this site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(this).find('ul').slideDown('slow');`

Assuming that your `$(this)` is grabbed correctly, also I don't think 'normal' is an option for `slideDown()`

Comment: Ok but what about the `.click` section what is the good selection to the elements inside the parent div ?

Comment: It seems incomplete answer as user is selecting inner elements in selector, how can you use `$(this).find('ul')` in this case?

Answer (score -1):

Why are you binding events on `ID`s? it should be on class.

Code:

```
$('.select_img, .select_text, .select_arrow').click(function(){
    $(this).siblings('ul').slideDown();
});
```

Fiddle: [http://jsfiddle.net/k7699nar/](http://jsfiddle.net/k7699nar/2/)

Comment: I think it's a typo, she/he just doesn't want to use that option :-)

Comment: Thanks but I don't want it this way I need to use the class inner elements

Comment: @bvl yes I (he) don't want to use this option

Comment: -1 first traverse wouldn't work so you replaced it with another that won't work. Try testing your solutions rather than guessing

Comment: @charlietfl you can check the fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/k7699nar/ & provide your suggestions, if any.

Comment: use `siblings()` next will only work if element is the next one. Read the docs

Comment: thanks for pointing out that @charlietfl. I have modified the code accordingly. However, user didn't mentioned that UL element can be anywhere. :) but yes, `siblings()` is better.

Comment: that's irrelevant, any element can only have one next element and 2 siblings can't have the same next